# Repeating Button - If you keep it depressed, it keeps firing a function

Tags: html, button, zooming, repeater

I am not sure what to call this, all I can think of is a Repeater Button.

I want to press a button and it fires a function immediately once, eg MyZoom(InOrOut).

But if I keep the mouse button depressed it will keep firing that MyZoom(InOrOut) every one tenth of a second until I release the mouse button.

As you can probably guess from the function name, I will have 2 buttons, a zoom in and a zoom out. They will call MyZoom(-1) to make it smaller and MyZoom(1) to make it bigger.

```
<button onclick="MyZoom(-1);">Zoom Out</button>
<button onclick="MyZoom(1);">Zoom In</button>
```

How can I change this to include the repeating effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events.

In `onmousedown` start an interval and stop it in `onmouseup`.

Here's a small example using jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="zoomButton" data-zoom="out">Zoom Out</button>
<button class="zoomButton" data-zoom="in">Zoom In</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var zoomIntervals = {};
$('.zoomButton').on('mousedown', function() {
    var mode = $(this).data('zoom');
    zoomIntervals[mode] = setInterval(function() {
        // here you perform your action.
        // check if mode == 'in' or mode == 'out' to determine if
        // the user is zooming in or out
    }, 100);
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    var mode = $(this).data('zoom');
    clearInterval(zoomIntervals[mode]);
    del zoomIntervals[mode];
});
```

If you do not (want to) use jQuery, use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to register the events and either access the data properties directly (**not compatible with older browsers**) or use e.g. the ID property to identify the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for this. There is an event called [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) and another event called [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) that would help you to do that. Basically mousedown event starts a timer (repeating it) that gets stopped when mouseup event is fired.

You could have something like this:

```
$('#myzoominbutton').mousedown(function() {
  alert('zooming is cool');
});
```